# Angular2 - Webpack : how to minimize the bundle correctly

Tags: angular, webpack

I tried to add the **--optimize-minimize** option in my *webpack* command( 2.1.0-beta.27) , but I still get a bundle.js, not a bundle.min?js :

```
"build:production": "node_modules/.bin/del-cli public/js/app && 
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && 
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && 
node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --optimize-minimize  --progress --profile --bail && 
node_modules/.bin/del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 
'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js'
'!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts'
'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'"
```

I also have the **UgifyJsPlugin** in my *webpack.config.prod.js*

```
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: false
    }),
```

Is it enough or something missing ?
Does it worth also to gzip the bundle or not ? if yes, how should I perform it ? ( Nginx )

thanks for feedback

Comment: Webpack has nothing to do with gzipping. Please ask that in a separate question.

Comment: My initial questionn was relative to any webpack plugin able to perform the compression aver minification , sorry for asking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name `bundle.js` is arbitrary. It's something you have set in your Webpack config, probably in your `output.path` setting. Look at the actual contents of the file to see if it's minified, which it will be if you're using the Uglify webpack plugin.

Comment: thanks , so the command option + the plugin parameter I added are well defined (?) I'll check the output content ..

Comment: Thanks a lot , it's actually minimized , not necessary to change the name